# OpenCV : findContours behaves differently with v2 and v3

Tags: python, opencv, version, contour

I am working on a project where I detect objets on the ground. I was doing this process with findContours on OpenCV 2, but then I needed some functions which are only available on OpenCV 3.

The thing is, with the exact same parameters, the function 'findContours' does not give me the same results with OpenCV 2 and 3.

There is a different number of contours, and the contours have different lengths.

Is it known that the functions behave differently between the two versions or is there something I am missing ?

Comment: I'm experiencing something close: the results are different with OpenCV 3.2.0 on Mac and on iPhone. Submitting the same image with the same algorithm produce different behavior on both platforms. Strange and problematic issue.

Comment: Apparently, it has something to do with the frame. The documentation says that the 1-pixel border of the image is set to 0, but apparently it is not the case with OpenCV3.2 ! (that's all I know)